# UnicodeDecodeError in for loop

Tags: arcpy, csv, python-2.7, unicode

I am getting a `unicode` error while using a combination of an `UpdateCursor` and `csv reader`. I'm trying to fix field values that got messed up because ArcGIS didn't read the CSV properly when it imported the table. What is odd is that the script functions for several iterations of my loop `for row in csvReader` before my nested loop `for i, fldName in enumerate (flds)` fails. The code:

```
with open (cv, "rb") as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader (csvFile)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc, flds) as uCurs:
        for row in csvReader:
            if first:
                first = False
                continue
            uCurs.next ()
            for i, fldName in enumerate (flds):
                #continue
                fldType = fldTypeDi [fldName]
                if fldType in ("Double", "Integer",
                               "Single", "SmallInteger"):
                    try: row [i] = float (row [i])
                    except:
                        if row [i] == "":
                            row [i] = None
                        else:
                            try:
                                row [i] = float (row [i].replace (",", ""))
                            except:
                                print "!!fail!!", flds [i], v, type (v)
                                failFlds.update ([(flds [i], type (v))])
                                row [i] = None
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/e1b8/Desktop/E1B8/AC Inspection/fix fields.py", line 47, in <module>
    for i, fldName in enumerate (flds):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Why would the script be trying to decode a unicode in the middle of a `for` loop? If I use the `continue` at the start of the script no errors result.

Comment: for i, fldName in enumerate (unicode(flds).encode('utf_8')):

Comment: Highly recommend replacing the built-in `csv` module with external `unicodecsv` (https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) which handles the unicode out-of-the-box. All the syntax will remain the same and all your strings will be by default unicode, no need to encode/decode anything.

Comment: Have you tried this without the cursor? I'd expect it to fail due to the limitations of `csv`

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I tried to install `unicodecsv` (`setup.py install` in the command prompt) and it seems to have installed, but `unicodecsv.py` didn't show up in my `lib` folder after installation. I'm not sure what that's about.

Comment: `pip install unicodecsv` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following code:

```
for row in csvReader:
            row = [unicode (r, errors = "replace") if type (r) == type ("") else r for r in row]
```